# Save to excel from Pandas with two keys in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to create a dataframe and write it to excel. I have multiple keys in pandas and when I write to excel, each key becomes a column in the sheet. What I would like to have is two keys in column under a main column name. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [], "B": [], "C_1": [], "C_2": []})
df = df.append({"A": 1, "B": 2, "C_1": 3, "C_2": 4})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("data.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

The above code produces the following table in the excel file.

```
| A | B | C_1 | C_2 |
---------------------
| 1 | 2 |  3  |  4  |
```

However, the keys `C_1` and `C_2` are the sub-divisions of key `C` and my expected output is

```
| A | B |     C     |
|   |   | C_1 | C_2 |
---------------------
| 1 | 2 |  3  |  4  |
```

I have looked at [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), which achieves what I want but I am not sure how to mix it with columns like `A` where there is no sub-division. How can this I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but you can try creating multilevel column like this:

```
cols = [(i.split('_')[0],i) if len(i.split('_'))>1 else (i,'') for i in df.columns]    
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```

---

```
    A   B   C
            C_1 C_2
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
```